# how to set permissions in SAMBA Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: samba, ubuntu-20.04

I have a SAMBA server on ubuntu 20.04. I have a folder with sbfolders with different permissions for different users, then I create a folder that can be accessed by all users with 777 permissions. When a user creates a folder or adds a file, the 777 permissions are not set, permissions are set that only can he write to the file? Does anyone know how I can configure it so that when a user creates a folder inside, everyone has 777 permissions?

Comment: the best fix I've found for this, is to put the users in a group, set the existing directories to be owned by that group, and use SetGID to ensure that all users of the group get the permissions of the parent directory for new files/dirs. combine with the samba Create Mask settings on the share definition. alternatively you can set umask to 000. Keep in mind, there is very rarely a reason to set anything to 777. 770 is usually more than sufficient.

Comment: but if a user creates a directory, the owner is the user who created it, not the group

Comment: the owner user is the user who created it, but the owner group is the owner group from the parent directory, if SetGID is set on the parent.

Comment: should chmod g+s of the root folder affect all new directories that are created?

Comment: well, you would want to run it recursively, so that dirs created inside of existing dirs are also set to use SetGID. I would probably do `chmod -R 2770 /path/`, but you could just put -R on your command. also when you say root folder, you mean the root of the share, not the root of the system right? all directories in the system root "/" must be owned by root:root.

Comment: How can I make all new folders inherit the permissions of compartida/
if i create a new directory it does not inherit permissions 770

Comment: use the samba create and directory mask settings on the share definition, or take a look at umask